# Navigate webpage without loading images in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm successfully opening pages with

```
    Dim o As Object

    o = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    o.navigate2("http://www.google.com")
```

Is it possible to navigate webpage without loading images ?

Answer (score -2):

1) This is VBS or VB6, not VB.Net.
2) You are essentially starting IE, it's up to the user to go to their options and
let IE load up images or not.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: 1) It's vb.net 2) Yes, I do. 3) What's the point of asking what I will do ? I'm asking a question here.

Comment: This is more suited to a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to add a comment, unless I'm commenting my own answer. *points out that I have 1 reputation*

Comment: I realise that you don't have the requred rep it doesn't change the fact that _this is not an answer_